# ¿Diferencia entre mysqlconnection y using(mysqlconnection)?

Tags: c#, mysql

Mi pregunta es cual es la diferencia entre las siguientes conexion

Conexion Mysql sin USING

```
MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection("//CADENA DE XCONEXION");
```

//CODIGO;

Conexion MYSQL con USING

```
using (NpgsqlConnection cnx = new pgsqlConnection("//CADENA DE CONEXION"))
        {
            //CODIGO 
        }
```

La principal diferencia que yo me he observado que con la primera cadena de conexión si no la cierras no puedes ejecutar MysqlCommand,DataReader, etc  a la ves en cambio con la segunda cadena de conexión puede ejecutar el MysqlCommand,DataReader, etc si necesidad de cerrar la cadena de conexion

Comment: pero alli usas dos objetos diferentes MySqlConnection  se usa con MySql pero NpgsqlConnection  se usa con PostgreSql

Comment: si me confundi al momento de formular la pregunta pero los dos son MYSQL

Comment: La diferencia está explicada en la documentacion de [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). Básicamente, con `using`, el objet `MySqlConnection` solo existe durante ese bloque, y el bloque se encarga de liberar todos los recursos asociados a ese objeto (llama al `Dispose` del objeto, que a su vez cierra la conexión) al finalizar el bloque.

Answer (score 2):

Al usa el bloque `using` lo que logras es asegurarte que actura el `pool de conexiones` lo cual es mas performante cuando creas y destruyes conexiones ya qe hay un pool activas que se reutilizan

[5.3 Using Connector/NET with Connection Pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html)

el using asegura que liberas correctamente el objeto de conexion, por eso es recomendable que lo utilices

Con ambas puedes ejecutar obtener un MySqlDataReader, tanto si usas

```
string connstring = "connection string";  
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connstring); 
cn.Open();  

string sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM Tabla";  
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);   

MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

if (reader.Read())  
{  
    //codigo
}  

cn.Close();
```

o que lo realices

```
string connstring = "connection string";  
using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connstring)) {  
    cn.Open();  

    string sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM Tabla";  
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);  

    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

    while(reader.Read())  
    {  
        //codigo
    }  

}
```

an ambas formas puedes realizar un loop del reader

Answer (score 0):

El using lo que hace es ejectuar `Dispose()` cuando se termina de ejecutar tu bloque de código.

Sería equivalente a hacer:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection("...");

try 
{
    // código
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // manejo de excepción
}
finally
{
    connection.Dispose();
}
```